# RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression does not match

Tags: c#, regex, customvalidator

I tested my regular expression online and it does what I want: only letters, numbers, parenthesis, -, and slash /.
Using the RegularExpressionValidator in C#,

It doesn't match my string and I get my ErrorMessage... I tested with the string :

"Asics 2018 - additional digital spend"

The code :

```
RegularExpressionValidator2.ValidationExpression = @"^[\w, \/ --()]";
RegularExpressionValidator2.ErrorMessage = $"No special character is allowed in the name";
```

I also tried : @"^[\w, / --()]"

How to use the validator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a single dash at the beginning or end of the [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) or else it's meaning will be to specify a range. Repeat the character class one or more times using `+` between asserting the start `^` and the end `$` of the string

`^[\w, /()-]+$`

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b%5cw%2c+%2f%28%29-%5d%2b%24&i=Asics+2018+-+additional+digital+spend%28%29-%2c_+&o=m)